# Delete AM/PM labels TimePickerDialog

Tags: java, android

I want delete AM/PM labels and add 00 to hour. I read about custom timePicker but I don't find solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may check the documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TimePicker.html

It seems that specifically setIs24HourView(Boolean is24HourView) would be a useful method to look at!